# How can I give my system application root permissions to bind privileged ports?

Tags: android, linux, tcp, port, bind

I´m developing an application that will be used on a managed platform. With managed platform I mean that it will run on a device that uses Android as a platform. No usual Android (phone/tablet applications will be installed, just custom company software).

The root file system is mounted as r/w and I'm able to push my apk file into /system/app/ and start my activity and services.

My goal is to provide a service running on a port lower then 1024. When binding this tcp port, I get the EACCES denied error message. How can I allow my application to bind to this port?

I have found the iptables solution, but unfortunately, the iptables executable doesn't work (segmentation faults). I am not able to recompile the platform, nor I have the platform signing key (the platform is provided as an installation on the target device).

My question is: how to give my application the rights to bind to a privileged port when I'm able to install my application as a system application and have root access (on adb shell) to the device.

Answer (score 0):

The 0-1023 is mostly used for other protocols.  Have you tried using a higher port?  Otherwise make sure the owner is correct, if not then use chown and make sure.  If those do not work supply the ls -l for the privileges.

Comment: Let me be more specific, I've created a UDP dns server that returns truncated. Default behaviour will be to retry on TCP port 53 for DNS. I want to use this TCP port 53 to bind to in order to provide a DNS server for the project. I can't workaround TCP. On which file should I do the chown? As the apk in /system/app is user root, group root and permissiosn 644, like the rest of the apks in that folder.